# Python - convert format string to f-string

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

How can I convert this to an f-string?

```
message = '{status} : {method} : {url}'.format(**call_components)
```

Comment: If you have variables with those names, then all you have to do is add the `f` to the beginning. e.g `f'...'`

Comment: ...and if you don't, then you can either use `call_components["status"]`, `call_components["method"]`, etc., or just use this `format` command because it works nicely. Not everything has to be f-strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

str.format() is usually fine, but if you really want an f-string then it would look like this:
`message = f'{call_components["status"]} : {call_components["method"]} : {call_components["url"]}'`

Comment: Which, arguably, is much harder to read than the `.format` solution. (Your solution is perfectly fine - but it would be better to stick to `.format` in such a case.)

Comment: Yes, I agree, I would use str.format() too, but this is the answer to the question...